# what is the number of elements in the set $(P \cap R) \cap Q$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set $P$ equals $\{ a,e,i,o,u\}$
The set $Q$ equals $\{ b,c,d,g,h\}$
The set $R$ equals $\{a,c,i,g,t,u\}$

What is the number of elements in the set $(P \cap R) \cap Q$?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. [Here is how I edited your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/86d3a929-4208-47ae-a01a-cd1ad08c6cc8/view-source).

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two sets consists of those things that belong to both of the sets. $P$ and $Q$ have absolutely no elements in common, so their intersection is empty: it’s the set with no elements, commonly written $\varnothing$, i.e., $P\cap Q=\varnothing$. We don’t even have to look at $R$ now to know that $(P\cap Q)\cap R$ is also empty: since there’s nothing in $P\cap Q$, there certainly isn’t anything that’s in **both** $P\cap Q$ and $R$! That is, $(P\cap Q)\cap R=\varnothing$ and therefore contains $0$ elements.

I have a suspicion that the problem may actually have been to find the number of elements in the set $(P\cup Q)\cap R$. (If not, this addendum won’t do any harm.) $P\cup Q$ is the union of $P$ and $Q$, the set of things belonging to at least one of the sets $P$ and $Q$; thus, $P\cup Q=\{a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,o,u\}$. Intersecting this with $R$ requires us to identify the things that are in both $P\cup Q$ and $R$:

$$(P\cup Q)\cap R=\{a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,o,u\}\cap\{a,c,i,g,t,u\}=\{a,c,i,g,u\}\;.$$

This set therefore has $5$ elements.